# Angular 5 : Allow trailing slash in routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

I'm updating an old website with Angular, and one of the requirements I have to meet is that all routes should remain the same as they were (For SEO purposes).

Many of the old website's routes finish with a slash (Like `/my/route/`), and some of them finish with a `.html`, like `/my/route.html`.

The issue is that routerLink deletes the final slash in every route finishing by a slash (My route is now `/my/route`).

How can I make `routerLink` to keep the trailing slash ?

A light example can be seen here : [AngularTrailingSlash](https://github.com/MarcBrillault/angularTrailingSlash).

Comment: what do you mean by many of your routes finish by / or .html? What routes are we talking about?

Comment: The routes of the old website I'm renewing with Angular. I want to have the same routes on the new one (For obvious SEO reasons).

Comment: Can't you just use 301 redirects?

Comment: Yes, I could do it, but a 301 redirect will lose some link juice, resulting in SEO loss, and I can't afford it with the amount of pages I'm managing.

Comment: Since Jul 2016 Google no longer penalize 301 redirect, so maybe you can really consider the 301 way, is way much cleaner that the other options.

Comment: @gmazzoti do you have a source? My internal SEO manager does not seemqto agree with you.

Comment: @MarcBrillault Apparently if you are migrating from Http to Https then a 301 redirect will not be penalized: https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added below to your `app.module.ts`

```
import {Location, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';


const _orig_prepareExternalUrl = PathLocationStrategy.prototype.prepareExternalUrl;

PathLocationStrategy.prototype.prepareExternalUrl = function(internal) {
  const url = _orig_prepareExternalUrl.call(this, internal);

  if (url === '') {
    return url;
  }

  console.log('For ' + internal + ' we generated ' + url);
  if (url.endsWith('.html')) {
      return url;
  }

  if (url.endsWith('/')) {
    return url;
  }


  return url + '/';

};

Location.stripTrailingSlash = function (url) {
    const /** @type {?} */ match = url.match(/#|\?|$/);
    const /** @type {?} */ pathEndIdx = match && match.index || url.length;
    const /** @type {?} */ droppedSlashIdx = pathEndIdx - (url[pathEndIdx - 1] === '/' ? 1 : 0);
    const first = url.slice(0, droppedSlashIdx);
    const last = url.slice(pathEndIdx);

    if (first.endsWith('.html')) {
        return first + last;
    }

    return first + '/' + last;

};
```

And it now works for me with a trailing slash when `.html` is not there

Comment: I maybe wrong, but I hadn't any difference when I tried : links generated on the template were still missing the last slash.

Comment: Okie I didn't look at the generation part rather just browsing the URL part. Will look into it

Comment: @MarcBrillault, I have a possible fix for the same but I believe your project has some error. When I click link I get `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null`. Can you fix that in your git repo first?

Comment: @MarcBrillault, I have added the changes. The url are now fine but your navigation issue is still there

Comment: I'm very sorry for the delay. Your answer works, thank you !

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have used above code, its working fine. But when i refresh the page it gives Error: Cannot match any routes. Can you please suggest me anything on this?

Comment: @MarcBrillault Is this code working properly for you on page refresh?

Comment: Sorry @Darshana, the code has been so updated since then, I will not be able to answer your question.

Comment: It won't worth page refresh. 
Try this way, it worked for me
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16051#issuecomment-575346573

Answer (score 2):

Even more improved code (based on code from Umesh).

Add on top of `main.ts`:

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
// Prevent stripping of trailing slash
Location.stripTrailingSlash = function stripTrailingSlashNew(url: string) {
  return url;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me:

```
export const contactUsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'contact-us/.', component: ContactUsComponent
    }
];
```

.
.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/contact-us/.']">Contact us</a>
```

And add below code in your main.ts:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

const __stripTrailingSlash = (Location as any).stripTrailingSlash;
(Location as any).stripTrailingSlash = function _stripTrailingSlash(url: string): string {
  const queryString$ = url.match(/([^?]*)?(.*)/);
  if (queryString$[2].length > 0) {
    return /[^\/]\/$/.test(queryString$[1]) ? queryString$[1] + '.' + queryString$[2] : __stripTrailingSlash(url);
  }
  return /[^\/]\/$/.test(url) ? url + '.' : __stripTrailingSlash(url);
};
```

I have referred below link for this solution:

https://stackblitz.com/github/ssatz/Angular5-Preserve-Trailing-Slash

Comment: If I have to preserve slashes in the middle of URL then any possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the main.ts file to keep trailing slash in the routerLink.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
const __stripTrailingSlash = (Location as any).stripTrailingSlash;
(Location as any).stripTrailingSlash = function _stripTrailingSlash(url: string): string {
  return /[^\/]\/$/.test(url) ? url : __stripTrailingSlash(url);
}

// import main ng module
// bootstrap on document ready
```

Comment: Why `Location as any`?

Comment: This code does not work with url parameters like `path/?params`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Location class extends in `AppModule` like this:

*app.module.ts:*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class UnstripTrailingSlashLocation extends Location {
  public static stripTrailingSlash(url: string): string {
    return url;
  }
}
Location.stripTrailingSlash = UnstripTrailingSlashLocation.stripTrailingSlash;

@NgModule({
            ...
```